# Как выделить отдельные числа в переменной int на python

Tags: python

Входные данные: 10 12 14 16
Как выбрать отдельно каждое из этих чисел в переменной int?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так:

```py
a, b, c, d, e = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

Если кратко, то команда `input()` считывает стрку данных, `split()` делит эту строку на подстроки по пробелу, `map` приводит каждую подстроку к числу

Более подробно можно почитать в интернете